# Condicionales anidados no funcionan como espero

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un programa de una contrarreloj. En el menú, el caso 3 sirve para introducir nuevos dorsales y el tiempo que hicieron.

Cuando añado el primer dorsal funciona bien. Pero al meter el segundo dorsal aún cogiendo bien los datos, me aparece el mensaje de "El dorsal ya está en la base de datos".

Si meto un dorsal con su tiempo y seguidamente vuelvo a meter ese mismo dorsal, me dice " El dorsal ya está en la base de datos", pero si meto un dorsal/tiempo, seguidamente meto otro dorsal/tiempo y de tercero meto el mismo dorsal que el segundo, no me da el error, me pide el tiempo.

Con lo que no me está funcionando bien el código, probé varias formas y en todas tengo algún problema. Además creo que el break no lo debería de usar.

Dejo link a pastebin por si queréis ver el código completo: [Contrarreloj](https://pastebin.com/7egi3Jbq)

```
Public static void introducirTiempo(TiempoDorsal[] clasificacion) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el Dorsal");
    d = teclado.nextInt();
    if (finalizados > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < finalizados; i++) {
            if (clasificacion[i].dorsal == d) {
                System.err.println("El dorsal ya está en la base de datos");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Introduce el tiempoooo joeputa");
                t = teclado.nextInt();
                clasificacion[finalizados].dorsal = d;
                clasificacion[finalizados].tiempo = t;
                finalizados++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Intoduce el tiempo");
        t = teclado.nextInt();
        clasificacion[finalizados].dorsal = d;
        clasificacion[finalizados].tiempo = t;
        finalizados++;
    }
```

Comment: Creo que te darás cuenta del error si metes 3 dorsales distintos y haces que el  cuarto sea igual que el tercero

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por la respuesta, al final cambié la forma del código. Edito el post principal para dejarla a la vista.

Saludos!

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, [no edites la pregunta para poner la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Al final opté por la siguiente solución y parece que funciona perfectamente.

```
public static void introducirTiempo(TiempoDorsal[] clasificacion) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el Dorsal");
    d = teclado.nextInt();
    boolean encontrado = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < clasificacion.length && !encontrado; i++) {
        if (clasificacion[i].dorsal == d) {
            encontrado = true;
        }
    }
    if (encontrado) {
        System.err.println("El dorsal ya está en la base de datos");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Intoduce el tiempo");
        t = teclado.nextInt();
        clasificacion[finalizados].dorsal = d;
        clasificacion[finalizados].tiempo = t;
        finalizados++;
        if (t > peor_tiempo) {
            peor_tiempo = t;
        }
    }

}
```